# Liferay: How to get List of friendlyUrl using groupID

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

Is there any API where I can get All the friendlyURL related to particular groupID from group table.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Precaution upfront: Do not think in terms of database: This will lead you to manipulating the database sooner or later, which is a recipe for disaster. Never manipulate the database.

That being said, you can use [`GroupLocalService`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/GroupLocalService.html) (or [`GroupService`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/GroupService.html)) to obtain a [`Group`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/model/Group.html) object that has the method you're looking for. If you have a `themeDisplay` object where you are, e.g. in a portlet request handler, you can obtain the current group from it as well.